# Many-to-many relationship, select related elemens without a join

Tags: sql, database, linq, select, many-to-many

I have three tables, User, Product and Instruction. There is a many-to-many relationship between User and Product as well as a many-to-many relationship between Product and Instruction.

I need to get all the Instructions a specific User is allowed to see, that is every Instruction of every Product that is connected to the User.

I want to use method syntax and make use of the navigation properties to avoid joins. So at first I'm grabbing the products for the User and then make a select on the Instructions, like so:

```
Products.Where(product => product.User.Any(user => user.ID == id))
        .Select(product => product.Instructions).ToList();
```

However, this will not return a `List<Instruction>` but a `List<IEnumerable<Instruction>>` and thus throwing a compiler error "Cannot implicitly convert type ...".

I also tried:

```
Products.Where(product => product.User
        .Contains(User.Where(user => user.ID == id).First()))
    .Select(product => product.Instructions).ToList();
```

But I'm getting the same result with it. Even without the where clause I'm getting the same

```
Products.Select(product => product.Instructions).ToList();
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Shouldn't the select be supposed to create a list of the related entries instead of a list of a list, which is pretty useless?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid JOINs?

Comment: Well, joins are unhandy and that's what navigation properties are for. It's so much simpler this way, if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you're missing is a `Many`:

```
Products.Where(product => product.User.Any(user => user.ID == id))
        .SelectMany(product => product.Instructions).ToList();
```

`SelectMany` is basically `Select`, but it flattens the sequence too.